# Nginx location with proxy_pass not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm doing the given request `http://example.com/my/route/bar`, the request body has 5M, so want to use `client_max_body_size 0M` for the route `/my/route/*`. But I'm having trouble making nginx use my custom location when I have `proxy_pass` inside of it.

With the fist scenario I'm getting a '413 Request Entity Too Large' responde, which means the first location isn't being matched, and nginx is using the default location.

```
location /my/route {
    client_max_body_size 0M;

    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://fabio:9999;
}

location / {

    proxy_buffer_size           128k;
    proxy_buffers               4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://fabio:9999;
}
```

But if using the following scenario(changing `proxy_pass http://fabio:9999;` to `return 404;`) the request returns 404, which is the intended response.

```
location /my/route {
    client_max_body_size 0M;

    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    return 404;
}

location / {

    proxy_buffer_size           128k;
    proxy_buffers               4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://fabio:9999;
}
```

What am I doing wrong on the first scenario? I need the `location /my/route` to be matched using `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the first location into `/`. Then set the specific config in the nested location block.
Here's an example (haven't tested it):

```
location / {
    location /my/route {
        client_max_body_size 0M;
    }

    proxy_buffer_size           128k;
    proxy_buffers               4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://fabio:9999;
}
```

Comment: The suggested config doesn't use the proxy_pass, it tries to access a file, returning 404. Nginx log: `"/etc/nginx/html/my/route/bar" failed (2: No such file or directory)`